# How can I authenticate Google Cloud Translate from PHP?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-api-php-client, google-translate

I'm trying to use the [google/cloud-translate](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries) library (v ^1.5) in Laravel (v ^6.0).

In `GoogleController.php`:

```
public function translate(Request $request) {
    $request->validate([
        'source' => 'required|string|min:2|max:5',
        'target' => 'required|string|min:2|max:5',
        'q' => 'required|string',
    ]);

    $translate = new TranslateClient([
        'keyFile' => base_path(config('services.google.json_path')),
        'projectId' => config('services.google.project_id'),
        'suppressKeyFileNotice' => true,
    ]);

    // Translate text from english to french.
    $result = $translate->translate($request->q, [
        'target' => explode($request->target, '-')[0],
        'source' => explode($request->source, '-')[0],
    ]);

    return $result;
}
```

But calling the route in Postman gives me the error:

```
Argument 2 passed to Google\Auth\CredentialsLoader::makeCredentials() must be of the type array, string given, called in /[...]/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/RequestWrapperTrait.php on line 155
```

I've checked that the projectId and the path to the keyFile is correct. Can anyone shed some light on how to get past this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're specifying the path to the key file, so you should use the `keyFilePath` parameter instead.

Try this:

```php
$translate = new TranslateClient([
    'keyFilePath' => base_path(config('services.google.json_path')),
    ...
]);
```

From the [`TranslateClient.__construct`](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.115.0/translate/translateclient?method=__construct) docs:

- `keyFile`: The contents of the service account credentials .json file retrieved from the Google Developer's Console. Ex: `json_decode(file_get_contents($path), true)`.
- `keyFilePath`: The full path to your service account credentials .json file retrieved from the Google Developers Console.